# Possible way to use desktop applications on your android device with almost no lag in remote area?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, remote-desktop, android, vnc

Can you use a Wireless LAN connection and appropriate device(s) to link an android smartphone and a desktop computer in a remote area, such as Antarctica, so that the smartphone can use an app like teamviewer or VNC to view the screen of the desktop (and therefore control it and its powerful desktop applications) without the annoying lag of satellite internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over a local WAN there is no reason that Microsoft's Remote Desktop shouldn't work. Given that your Android is supported, they even have an app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.rdc.android&hl=en

When you launch the app just provide the IP address of your desktop machine and away you go. Oh yeah and don't forget to enable RDP on the desktop.

Answer (score -1):

I think this will allways be a question of your up and download speed. If your connection is slow / bad it does not realy matter what you are using.

You could/should do a test with a normal connection and trace with tools how much data you transfer. The programm that transfers less data will also be "faster" when you are using bad internet connections.

As well i have to mention here professional remote work application called citrix but you will need a server and licence stuff to use it.

Comment: my question is basically - do you have to rely on the satellites / dsl in the wall / etc to send wireless packets of information between smartphones/computers (over short distances) or can you really just make your own "mini internet"

Comment: Well if its a short distance you could try to make your own radio relay system to transfer the data :P.